# A problem about measure theory, sigma algebra and Borel sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, borel-measures

> **Problem:** Let $\mathcal{S}=\{(-b,b): b\geq 0\}$. Is $\sigma(\mathcal{S})=\mathfrak{B}o(\mathbb{R})$?

> **Notation:** $\sigma(\mathcal{S})$ is the *sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{S}$* and $\mathfrak{B}o(\mathbb{R})$ is the *Borel sigma algebra*.

**My attempt:** I think it's *true*. My approach to this problem is as follows:

By definition in theory of sets, we need to prove two parts:

1. $\sigma(\mathcal{S})\subseteq \mathfrak{B}o(\mathbb{R})$.
2. $\mathfrak{B}o(\mathbb{R})\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{S})$.

Now, for to prove $\boxed{1}$, let's define $$\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{R})=\text{collection of all open sets of $\mathbb{R}$}.$$
and since that by definition $\boxed{\mathfrak{B}o(\mathbb{R})=\sigma(\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{R}))}$, we can see that $$\mathcal{S}\subseteq  \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{R}) \implies \sigma(\mathcal{S}) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{R})) \quad \text{and since that $\sigma(\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{R}))\subseteq \mathfrak{B}o(\mathbb{R})$ we have} \quad  \sigma(\mathcal{S})\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{R}))\subseteq \mathfrak{B}o(\mathbb{R}).$$

Finally, for to prove $\boxed{2}$, we need to remember that and every open set is the countable and disjoint union of open intervals, so we obtain $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{R})\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{S})$, so $$\mathfrak{B}o(\mathbb{R})\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{S}).$$

**Is it correct?** **any suggestion?**
Thanks!

Comment: The first one is correct. For the second statement, I think that you can't generate all the open sets using unions and intesections of symetric (around zero) open intervals. That last thought makes me think that the problem's claim isn't true.

Comment: How do obtain an arbitrary interval from $\mathcal{S}$? Note that all elements of $\mathcal{S}$ are symmetric wrt the origin and that property is stable under union and complementation.

Comment: @rarwoan Thanks your clarification helped me to see my mistake.

Comment: @Thorgott the counterexample for the second part would be something like saying that $ (- 3,2) $ is not in $\sigma (S)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true as you showed that $\sigma(\mathcal S)$ is contained in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. It is true that an open set can be written as a countable disjoint union of open intervals. But you have also to prove that any open interval belongs to $\sigma(\mathcal S)$, which is actually not the case.

Let
$$
\mathcal B:=\{A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R), A=-A\},
$$
where $-A:=\{-a,a\in A\}$. It is possible to show that $\mathcal B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal S$ and that it is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra having this feature.

Comment: :( Ok, I saw my mistake. Thank you very much, I am studying measure theory on my own and these are my first steps in solving problems.